# How to prevent mutGaussian from putting out of range values into genomes of chromosome in DEAP Python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, deap

I have used

```
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutGaussian, mu=1, sigma=1, indpb=10)
```

code for mutation. The function puts values out of the range into the chromosome's genomes. Is there any way to prevent it? In other words, is there any way to keep the value of each genome in its specific range?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is taken from the [deap documentation](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part2.html#tool-decoration):

```
def checkBounds(min, max):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
            offspring = func(*args, **kargs)
            for child in offspring:
                for i in xrange(len(child)):
                    if child[i] > max:
                        child[i] = max
                    elif child[i] < min:
                        child[i] = min
            return offspring
        return wrapper
    return decorator

toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxBlend, alpha=0.2)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutGaussian, mu=0, sigma=2)

toolbox.decorate("mate", checkBounds(MIN, MAX))
toolbox.decorate("mutate", checkBounds(MIN, MAX))
```